# Haskell State Monad Example

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I'm experimenting with Haskell's `Control.Monad.State` by trying to iterate through a list of either strings or integers, counting them, and replacing string entries with the integer `0`. I have managed to do the counting part, but failed in creating the replaced list. Here is my code
which correctly prints `[3,6]` to the screen. How can I make it create the desired list `[6,0,3,8,0,2,9,1,0]`?

```
module Main( main ) where

import Control.Monad.State

l = [
    Right 6,
    Left "AAA",
    Right 3,
    Right 8,
    Left "CCC",
    Right 2,
    Right 9,
    Right 1,
    Left "D"]

scanList :: [ Either String Int ] -> State (Int,Int) [ Int ]
scanList [    ] = do
    (ns,ni) <- get
    return (ns:[ni])
scanList (x:xs) = do
    (ns,ni) <- get
    case x of
        Left  _ -> put (ns+1,ni)
        Right _ -> put (ns,ni+1)
    case x of
        Left  _ -> scanList xs -- [0] ++ scanList xs not working ...
        Right i -> scanList xs -- [i] ++ scanList xs not working ...

startState = (0,0)

main = do
    print $ evalState (scanList l) startState
```

Comment: You don't actually need the State monad for either of these tasks, both can be done with basic "pure" list functions. I guess you know this and were just doing this for learning purposes, but thought I should mention it in case you thought you needed state for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[0] ++ scanList xs` doesn't work because `scanList xs` is not a list, but a `State (Int,Int) [Int]`. To fix that, you will need to use `fmap`/`<$>`.

You will also need to change the base case to not make the state value be the return value.

```
scanList :: [Either String Int] -> State (Int, Int) [Int]
scanList []     = return []
scanList (x:xs) = do
    (ns,ni) <- get
    case x of
        Left  _ -> put (ns+1, ni)
        Right _ -> put (ns, ni+1)
    case x of
        Left  _ -> (0 :) <$> scanList xs
        Right i -> (i :) <$> scanList xs
```

To further simplify the code, however, it would be good to use `mapM`/`traverse` and `state` to remove most of the boilerplate of the recursion and `get`/`put` syntax.

```
scanList :: [Either String Int] -> State (Int, Int) [Int]
scanList = mapM $ \x -> state $ \(ns, ni) -> case x of
    Left  _ -> (0, (ns+1, ni))
    Right i -> (i, (ns, ni+1))
```

Comment: thanks it works! how would you translate `(0 :) <$> scanList xs` to English? I would say "apply the concatenation of 0 to every element of <something>" but what is <something> ... it doesn't make sense here (?)

Comment: The "apply a function to every element of the list" definition of `fmap` is only for the list monad. The `fmap` definition used here is for the state monad, which is to "apply a stateless function `f` to the result of the stateful computation `m` in `fmap f m`". If it's easier to understand, think of it as shorthand for `scanList xs >>= return . (0 :)`