# Manipulating Haskell Monad State

Tags: haskell, monads

Somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603200/haskell-monad-state-example), I'm trying to figure out
how to move around a Haskell Monad state.
Each `Employee` in a team is replaced with a corresponding `Employee'`
while maintaining some simple state. Here is the code:

```
module Main( main ) where
import Control.Monad.State

data Employee  = EmployeeSW  Int Int | EmployeeHW Int String deriving ( Show )
data Employee' = EmployeeSW'     Int | EmployeeHW'    String deriving ( Show )

scanTeam :: [Employee] -> State (Int,Int) [Employee']
scanTeam [    ] = return []
scanTeam (p:ps) = scanEmployee p -- : scanTeam ps ???

scanEmployee :: Employee -> State (Int,Int) Employee'
scanEmployee (EmployeeSW id s) = do
    (num,raise) <- get
    put (num+1,raise)
    return (EmployeeSW' (s+raise))
scanEmployee (EmployeeHW id s) = do
    (num,raise) <- get
    put (num+1,raise)
    return (EmployeeHW' (s++(show raise)))

startState = (0,3000)

t = [(EmployeeHW 77 "Hundred"),(EmployeeSW 66 500),(EmployeeSW 32 200)]

main = print $ evalState (scanTeam t) startState
```

I want to eventually concatenate `scanEmployee p` with `scanTeam ps`,
so I tried to extract the pieces of `scanEmployee p` and somehow glue
them together with `scanTeam ps`. So far I failed miserably.
Actually, I'm not even sure the state can be moved around between them (?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `State` is a monad, you can use `do` notation to define `State` computations.
(`State`'s instance of `Monad` plumbs the state through, so the ending state of one statement in the `do` block becomes the starting state of the next.)

So, in a `do` block, I'm going to:

1. Process the first `Employee` in the list to get a new `Employee`
2. Process the rest of the list recursively
3. Put the two results back together and use them as the return value for the `State`ful computation.

```hs
scanTeam :: [Employee] -> State (Int,Int) [Employee']
scanTeam [    ] = return []
scanTeam (p:ps) = do
    newP <- scanEmployee p
    newPs <- scanTeam ps
    return (newP:newPs)
```

It turns out that "`map` in a monadic context" is pretty useful in general, so it's present in the standard prelude as [`mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) (aka [`traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:traverse), if you're ready to go down the rabbit hole).

```hs
scanTeam = mapM scanEmployee
```